# How to extract embedded fonts from pdf file using fontforge script

Tags: embedded-fonts, fontforge

I am trying to extract fonts from pdf file using following fontforge script

```
Open("file.pdf")
file = $firstfont
while ( file != "" )
   Open(file)
   Print($fontname)
   file = $nextfont
endloop
```

This only loads one font but if I open same pdf file using fontforge gui it shows 7 fonts. Can I get some help.